# Laser scan to probabilistic map based on occupancy grid

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I would like to transform laser data (LaserScan) in a local 2D occupancy grid (OccupancyGrid). I tried to use "gmapping" and it worked well. But gmapping builds a global map while I only need the local one.

Is there a simple solution (a package or a node) to build a local map around the robot? Could you please tell me what should I do in details? or show me some references?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205721/laser-scan-to-probabilistic-map-based-on-occupancy-grid/) by [sadek](https://answers.ros.org/users/21940/sadek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2015-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I finally found a node ROS that can do that. But can be run only on ROS Indigo. More information on this page : http://wiki.ros.org/local_map

---

Originally posted by [sadek](https://answers.ros.org/users/21940/sadek/) with karma: 58 on 2015-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jmrrosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/27563/jmrrosa/) on 2016-09-19**:
Hi!
Can you please tell me how do you run the local_map? I'm tried to run the package but it tells me that there is no executable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to me like gmapping would still work. Just remap ~map_frame to some local map frame that you have defined, and also set a static transform between the robot base and this local frame.. After that, you'll have to manage the global map <--> odometry frame transform by some other means, but it should accomplish what you need.

---

Originally posted by [TimboInSpace](https://answers.ros.org/users/11216/timboinspace/) with karma: 141 on 2015-03-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1